# How do I translate a boolean type method into a void one in Java?

Tags: java, boolean, void, recursive-backtracking

I am making a sudoku solver for a school assignment in Java, using backtracking. I have successfully solved it using a *boolean solveSudoku()* method but in the template provided by the teacher, the method is listed as *void solveSudoku()*. It clearly says in the requirements to use the methods as given, but I am having a hard time changing my code.

This is my initial method :

(The int[] findEmptySquare(), as the name suggests returns the indexes of the next empty cell in the sudoku.)

```
 boolean solveSudoku() {
    int[] arr = new int[2];
    arr = findEmptySquare();
    if (arr != null) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            if (givesConflict(row, col, i) == false) {
                int x = row, y = col;
                grid[row][col] = i;
                if (solveSudoku()) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    grid[row][col] = 0;
                    row = x;
                    col = y;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    //solutionCounter++;
    return true;

}
```

I have tried to mimic the boolean modus operandi in a void method like this :

```
 boolean okay;
void solveSudoku() {
    int[] arr = new int[2];
    arr = findEmptySquare();
    if (arr != null) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            
            if (givesConflict(row, col, i) == false) {
                int x = row, y = col;
                grid[row][col] = i;
                if (okay == true) { //line 11
                    solveSudoku();
                     okay = true;
                    return;
                } else {
                    grid[row][col] = 0;
                    row = x;
                    col = y;
                }
            }
        }
       okay = false;
        return; 
    }
    okay = true;
    return; 
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as intended. If on line 11 I replace it with if(okay == false), the program runs until it gets stuck with no correct number to fill, and then the backtracking doesn't start.

Could anyone provide a hint in what way I can successfully tranform this method?
I would greatly appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: since there is recursive regardless `if (solveSudoku())`, try calling `solveSudoku();` first, then `if (okay == true) { return;} else...`

Comment: I observe that there's only one recursive call to solveSudoku. and once that returns true, you unwind the call stack to return all the way back to the original calls.  That suggests introducing a member variable that gets set true where you see that there are no empty squares and never setting it false.  (Also, I'd name that variable 'solved' rather than 'okay').

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you for clarifying! Calling the method before the if solved the problem. It has been a while since I last worked with recursion and I really needed a fresh pair of eyes. Now it makes sense how it works.